# C# Deleting File "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, image, pdf, delete-file, pdfsharp

I'm trying to add a picture of part of a form to a PDF so I'm using PDFsharp, but one of the problems I have is that I can't delete the picture after I have added it to the PDF file.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"c:\\Temp.jpeg";
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(314, this.Height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    bmp.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    GeneratePDF("test.pdf",path);
    var filestream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    filestream.Close();
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}

private void GeneratePDF(string filename, string imageLoc)
{
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    // Create an empty page or load existing
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    DrawImage(gfx, imageLoc, 50, 50, 250, 250);

    // Save and start View
    document.Save(filename);
    Process.Start(filename);
}

void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string jpegSamplePath, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
}
```

The `FileStream` is there because I was trying to make sure that it was closed and if that was the problem.
This is where I got the code for writing the picture to the PDF [overlay-image-onto-pdf-using-pdfsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854935/overlay-image-onto-pdf-using-pdfsharp) and this is where I got the code to make a picture of the form [capture-a-form-to-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623237/capture-a-form-to-image)

Did I miss something obvious?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't use such astonishing title!

Comment: Why do you can't delete it? Did you get an exception?

Comment: the only thing i get is "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: @LeiYang what would have been a good title?

Comment: It's your application that not working, not C#.

Comment: using a `using` block would make the solution a little more elegant. Have a look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the details of the `System.IO.IOException` it tells you that

> the file cannot be accessed because it is used by another process.

The process that is still using your image is this nice object:

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath);
```

The solution would be to dispose the image after you have drawn it to the PDF:

```
void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string jpegSamplePath, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);

    image.Dispose();
}
```

And now the Exception vanishes into thin air....as does your file...

**EDIT**

A more elegant solution would be use a `using` block, this will make sure that `Dispose()` is called after you are finished with the file:

```
void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string jpegSamplePath, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    using (XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath))
    {
        gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question "Or is there a better way to do this?"

Using a MemoryStream instead of a file would work around the issue. And it would improve performance. Workarounds are bad, but performance improvements are good.

The MemoryStream could be passed as a parameter. That's cleaner than having a fixed filename. And it makes no practical difference whether you pass a filename or a MemoryStream inside you program.